# c# image to byte array huge size

Tags: c#, image, byte

im just using a faster method to convert image to byte array it's not new i found it in some places over the internet.

this is the send code

```
private  int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
    {
       total = 0;
        int size = data.Length;
        int dataleft = size;
        int sent;


        datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        sent = s.Send(datasize);


            sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
            total += sent;
            dataleft -= sent;
          //  MessageBox.Show("D");

        return total;
    }
```

and i call it :

```
    SendVarData(handler, bmpBytes);
```

where `handler` is a socket and `bmpbytes` is the image converted to byte array. do u have any better solution? @xanatos

Comment: Because you are probably loading a `jpg` or a `gif` image that is compressed... Try saving it to a `bmp` and see the size.

Comment: @xanatos thank you very much now i understand haha. but is there any way to compress it now using the first unsafe method?

Comment: The code is correct. The only thing you can try, as I wrote, is to create a NetworkStream just to send the bitmap and see if it is faster or not.

Comment: @xanatos allright i'll try it. a huge thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not weird at all. In your first sample, you're copying the image as it is stored in memory,  i.e. uncompressed.

In your second sample you're getting the data as it would have been stored on disk, i.e. compressed as GIF in this case.

Comment: oh i understand now. is there any one to compress it with the first unsafe method?

Comment: You're doing two completely different things. If you want it compressed, stick to the second method.

Comment: @itapi The second method is slow *because* it is compressing the image.

Comment: The reason it's slower is because it's compressing the image. Maybe there's some heavily optimized GIF compression libraries out there somewhere, but I'd think the code in GDI would be pretty good.

Comment: @itapi It is probably possible to build a faster `MemoryStream`, but I don't think you would gain very much. To see how much it can be speedup, try constructing the MemoryStream with `new MemoryStream(1000000)`. If it is much faster (I don't think), I'll write some line of code.

Comment: @xanatos it's not much faster buy i really need it cuz i use fast transfer server(using socket) so i would apriciate if you could write here a code

Comment: @itapi If you use sockets, then the best thing is that you directly write to the stream of the socket, without passing through the `MemoryStream` and the `ToArray()`.

Comment: @xanatos in my code i just use the `Socket.Send()` method look at the question i'll post a part of my code there i would like to hear your opinion cuz its sounds like u have a better knowledge  than me :)

Comment: @itapi You could try `new NetworkStream(Socket)` and using that `Stream` instead of the `MemoryStream`

Comment: @xanatos i used networkstream once but now i use socket send i think it's better but i still  want your opinion look at the edited question

Comment: @itapi The `NetworkStream` class is basically just a wrapper around a `Socket`, so why not try it..!